# Как правильно сократить "10 метров": 10м или 10 м?

Tags: орфография

Есть ли какое-либо правило написания индексов чисел?
То есть через пробел или нет? Я склоняюсь к написанию через пробел.

Answer (score 1):

Да, разумеется, пробел нужен

Answer (score 1):

Пробел, конечно, нужен. Только это не индекс, а сокращение (используемое как условное обозначение единицы измерения).